# How to remove <br> using jquery

Tags: jquery

This is my html

```html
<div class="ch-list">
   <p><a>Ch 1</a><br><a>Ch 2</a></p>
   <br>
   <p><a>Ch 3</a><br><a >Ch 4</a></p>
</div>
<div class="pg-list">
   <p><a>pg 1</a><br><a>pg 2</a></p>
   <br>
   <p><a>pg 3</a><br><a>pg 4</a></p>
</div>
```

If I do the following

```js
$("p,.ch-list").children('br').remove();
```

it remove all  < br >
It become like this

```html
<div class="ch-list">
   <p><a>Ch 1</a><a>Ch 2</a></p>
   <p><a>Ch 3</a><a>Ch 4</a></p>
</div>
<div class="pg-list">
   <p><a>pg 1</a><a>pg 2</a></p>
   <p><a>pg 3</a><a>pg 4</a></p>
</div>
```

i don't know how to only remove < br > between < a > in class=ch-list not include other < br > between < p > or < br > from other class
i want to make something like this

```html
<div class="ch-list">
   <p><a>Ch 1</a><a>Ch 2</a></p>
   <br>
   <p><a>Ch 3</a><a>Ch 4</a></p>
</div>
<div class="pg-list">
   <p><a>pg 1</a><br><a>pg 2</a></p>
   <br>
   <p><a>pg 3</a><br><a>pg 4</a></p>
</div>
```

Please tell me how to do
Sorry for my bad english

Comment: `$("p a br,.ch-list a br").remove()`

Comment: @Justinas will `p a br` not remove from all include in `pg-list` where OP don't want it removed? Also there is not br inside an `<a>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".ch-list p").children('br').remove();
```

Comment: this scripts short and work well, thanks you

Comment: Why would you use `.children()` you can do it like `$(".ch-list p > br").remove();` it's more clean

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this, since you say you want to remove `<br>` that is between 2 x `<a>`:

```
$('.ch-list p br').filter(function() {
  if ($(this).prev().is("a") && $(this).next().is("a")) {
    return this
  }
}).remove()
```

**Demo**

```js
$('.ch-list p br').filter(function() {
  if ($(this).prev().is("a") && $(this).next().is("a")) {
    return this
  }
}).remove()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ch-list">
  <p><a>Ch 1</a><br><a>Ch 2</a></p>
  <br>
  <p><a>Ch 3</a><br><a>Ch 4</a></p>
</div>
<div class="pg-list">
  <p><a>pg 1</a><br><a>pg 2</a></p>
  <br>
  <p><a>pg 3</a><br><a>pg 4</a></p>
</div>
```

Comment: this scritps work well, thanks you